# How to install spice-server correctly in CentOS 7 with the source codes?

Tags: linux, centos, qemu

I met a problem when I try to install QEMU with spice support.

It works well if I install spice-server with `yum`. In this case when I type `./configure --enable-spice` in root directory of QEMU's source codes, the spice-server can be detected correctly.

But now I want to install spice-server by compiling its source codes, cause I have some work to do with it.

I tried `./configure; make; make install` and `./configure --prefix=/usr; make; make install`. QEMU couldn't find spice-server installed in neither way. I just got

> ERROR: User requested feature spice
>         configure was not able to find it.
>         Install spice-server(>=0.12.0) and spice-protocol(>=0.12.3) devel

returned.

I don't have this problem in ubuntu, I don't know how to fix it in a CentOS server. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: IMHO should be asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to build qemu with spice from source code.

That involves many dependences and configurations. 
Especially while you have system-installed 'qemu' running.

Maybe https://github.com/grizzlybears/sqb can help you.

It is a set of helper scripts to automatically do the follwing:

1. Install build depend.
2. Get code from offical repository
3. Get 'fedora base cloud image' as test image
4. Autogen/configure/build qemu with spice in local dir, touch nothing in system
   5.Run test VM using our hand-made 'qemu'
5. Open spice console to the VM, if you have 'spice-gtk-tools' installed

Answer (score 0):

You should first clone spice-protocol manually and execute `./autogen.sh && ./configure &&make &&make install` and export the PKG_CONFIG_PATH `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH={your pkg config path}`